# How to get file name from Clipboard in Windows programmatically?

Tags: c++, windows, vbscript

I right-click on a file and copied it (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>), the filename is send to clipboard. Now I want to get that string (filename or filePath) from the clipboard.

Is there any function for getting filepath of the file copied to clipboard?

Comment: You should use Windows clipboard APIs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648709(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: When using the Windows clipboard APIs the following link is about files being copied: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: VBScript or C++?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers both ok.

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question is that you want to copy the File **NAME** and get it from the clipboard.

In vbscript, you can get the **TEXT** copied to your Clipboard by creating an IE object and using its Clipboard.getdata method as shown below. Copy the File **name**(not the file, but filename) first to your clipboard and run the vbscript code after performing the IE settings mentioned at the end.

```
set ieobj = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
ieobj.navigate "about:blank"
str = ieobj.Document.ParentWindow.ClipBoardData.getData("text")
msgbox str             'str contains whatever text is copied to your clipboard
```

NOTE: This script will only run if Active Scripting is enabled for IE. You can do the following setting before running this vbscript:

> Here are simple steps to turn on or turn off VBScript in your Internet
> Explorer:
>
> Follow Tools-> Internet Options from the menu.
>
> Select Security tab from the dialog box.
>
> Click the Custom Level button.
>
> Scroll down till you find Scripting option. Select Enable radio button
> under Active scripting. Finally click OK and come out.

[image]